# Shared Preferences on a Null Object Reference Android

Tags: java, android

I am new to android developing maybe its a silly question but please help me. I am getting this error while trying to save an int value.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

And here is my code

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = "com.example.app.value";
int i = prefs.getInt(value, 0);
```

And for write

```
prefs.edit().putInt(number, i).apply();
```

I just want to set a SharedPreferences and want to read it at the first and write it inside the Activity. How can I solve it?

EDIT

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "myprefs";
public static final  String value = "key";

int i = sharedpreferences.getInt(value, 0);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    i += 1;    
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(value, i);
    editor.apply();
}
```

I managed to save preferences with a different way but I couldn't manage to read it in MainActivity extends Activity class.

log :

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.content.SharedPreferences.getInt(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: `SharedPreferences prefs = yourActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: ^ yourActivity.this.getSharedPreferences() has no effect compared to directly calling getSharedPreferences(), since the provided code is already in the activity; you would only do it this way if you were in a utility class (in which case calling getSharedPreferences() directly wouldn't even compile). Also it is bad practice to hardcode the package name (this is a magic string), call getPackageName() instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is an example of `SharedPreferences`

To save `name` in SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, name);
        editor.apply();
```

To get `name` from SharedPreferences:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String name = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "default value");
```

For more details visit: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Updated Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "myprefs";
public static final  String value = "key";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int i = sharedpreferences.getInt(value, 0);
    //use the value of i where needed.
}
public void saveMessage(View view) {
    i += 1;    
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(value, i);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: use .apply() instead of commit()

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference      getting this error now

Comment: @SimbilliDev please post whole code of your activity in your question post. I will correct it.

Comment: Thanks for help. I found an other way to solve but this one also worked

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to use SharedPreferences. You will get more details about it in the link mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In my case this was the issues :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43160497/321015

I was calling shared prefereance before context was set. ideal way to call the context

`newContextbase.getSharedPreferences(..`

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it like this

```
public class PreferenceClass {
    public static final String PREFERENCE_NAME = "PREFERENCE_DATA";
    private final SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    public PreferenceClass(Context context) {
         sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
         int count = sharedpreferences.getInt("count", -1);
         return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
         editor.putInt("count", count);
         editor.commit();
    }

    public void clearCount() {
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
         editor.remove("count");
         editor.commit();
    }
}
```

getCount() will return -1 if no value is set.

Answer (score 2):

This question was for the "Simplify Networking with RetroFit" android course. I was getting this error because i didnt have my BaseApplication class in the Android Manifest...Everything is good now

Comment: Suffering with this error for two days. After reading your answer only I noticed I did not put my base application class in my manifest. Working good now