# Cannot get shared preferences inside custom context wrapper injection

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get a user's desired language stored in shared preferences, and use that to set the language of the app through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221711/android-context-getresources-updateconfiguration-deprecated/40704077#40704077) answer.

I have the same MyConxtextWrapper file as that answer but have changed the wrapper injection to:

```
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userLang", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String lang = sharedPref.getString("lang", "");


        super.attachBaseContext(MyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase,lang));
    }
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
04-01 18:35:25.648 25032-25032/com.example.c1629177.cymruniapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.c1629177.cymruniapp, PID: 25032
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.c1629177.cymruniapp/com.example.c1629177.cymruniapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:171)
     at com.example.c1629177.cymruniapp.MainActivity.attachBaseContext(MainActivity.java:194)
     at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:6175)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

How can I can pass the shared preference value "lang" into the line `super.attachBaseContext(MyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase,lang));` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're overriding `attachBaseContext()` which is used to attach the base context to your wrapper. At the moment when you're calling `getSharedPreferences()` the base context is not yet set and thus you're trying to get the `NullPointerException`.

So instead call this method directly on the `newBase` context:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = newBase.getSharedPreferences("userLang", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String lang = sharedPref.getString("lang", "");
    super.attachBaseContext(MyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, lang));
}
```

And maybe use a useful default for the language; instead of `""`.